# How can I fix java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError when creating a SparkSession?

Tags: java, windows, scala, apache-spark

I'm getting this error when running a project in IntelliJ:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\bin\java.exe" ...
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57229', transport: 'socket'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:1106)
    at my.org.MyClass.<init>(MyClass.scala:2)
```

In MyClass I just have:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("my app").getOrCreate()
```

These are the versions I have in pom.xml (using Maven with IntelliJ):

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I've tried running it in the command line instead and I get the same result.

I've confirmed my java version is 64 bits (Windows 11):

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_212"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b10, mixed mode)
```

Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by inconsistent / conflicting definitions for some class that is being passed in (I guess) the SparkSession.  At one point it is defined (or referred to) as a `class`.  Somewhere else, the same FQ name refers to an `interface`.  This might be in your code, or it might be in Spark code.  Unfortunately, the exception message doesn't tell us the name of the class that has been defined inconsistently.

<sup>Looking at the OpenJDK Java 8 source code, I think that this particular `IncompatibleClassChangeError` exception message is used when the native classloader is loading a class `X` that implements an interface `Y`.  At runtime, the `Y` that the classloader found  turns out to have been declared as a `class` rather than an `interface`.  This implies that `Y` has changed between compiling `X` and using it.</sup>

I suggest that you make sure that you are using identical Spark JAR files when compiling your code and when running it.  Also, make sure that you are not mixing Spark JARs from different versions.  Finally, make sure that you have recompiled *all* of your code, especially if you have changed Spark versions recently.